# Expect jasmine Spy to be called "eventually", before timeout

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I've written a lot of asynchronous unit tests lately, using a combination of Angular's `fakeAsync`, returning Promises from `async` test body functions, the Jasmine `done` callback, etc.  Generally I've been able to make everything work in a totally deterministic way.

A few parts of my code interact in deeply-tangled ways with 3rd party libraries that are very complex and difficult to mock out.  I can't figure out a way to hook an event or generate a Promise that's guaranteed to resolve after this library is finished doing background work, so at the moment my test is stuck using `setTimeout`:

```
class MyService {
  public async init() {
    // Assume library interaction is a lot more complicated to replace with a mock than this would be
    this.libraryObject.onError.addEventListener(err => {
      this.bannerService.open("Load failed!" + err);
    });
    // Makes some network calls, etc, that I have no control over
    this.libraryObject.loadData();
  }
}

it("shows a banner on network error", async done => {
    setupLibraryForFailure();
    await instance.init();

    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(banner.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
        done();
    }, 500);  // 500ms is generally enough... on my machine, probably
});
```

This makes me nervous, especially the magic number in the `setTimeout`.  It also scales poorly, as I'm sure 500ms is far longer than any of my other tests take to complete.

What I think I'd like to do, is be able to tell Jasmine to poll the `banner.open` spy until it's called, or until the test timeout elapses and the test fails.  Then, the test should notice as soon as the error handler is triggered and complete.  Is there a better approach, or is this a good idea?  Is it a built-in pattern somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take advantage of `callFake`, basically calling another function once this function is called.

Something like this:

```
it("shows a banner on network error", async done => {
    setupLibraryForFailure();
    // maybe you have already spied on banner open so you have to assign the previous
    // spy to a variable and use that variable for the callFake
    spyOn(banner, 'open').and.callFake((arg: string) => {
      expect(banner.open).toHaveBeenCalled(); // maybe not needed because we are already doing callFake
      done(); // call done to let Jasmine know you're done
    });
    await instance.init();
});
```

We are setting a spy on banner.open and when it is called, it will call the callback function using the callFake and we call done inside of this callback letting Jasmine know we are done with our assertions.

Comment: This is brilliant in its simplicity.  Works perfectly, thanks!